# Review process needs serious review!

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reopen-closed

I recently submitted the following question (yes it was a question), which has obviously been closed.

**[How can I offer a Delphi desktop utility application on the web as a service? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023081/how-can-i-offer-a-delphi-desktop-utility-application-on-the-web-as-a-service)**

This is what should be a perfect question. How do I take an application I have and make it available on the web.

Ideally, someone would answer with what would have to be done, and I would be on my way.

Perhaps it wasn't perfectly worded as some of the responses were far more afield than my question. And, maybe those comments derailed the reviewers as well. But with clarification there have also been good answers.

David Hefferin said it was not a web service but a web app. Okay, and even though I used web and service in the same sentence, I never said web service either. Still, we were getting there.

Instead it seems stackoverflow is looking for Little Questions, Techie Questions, that can be answered simply. This is a concept or direction question by someone who is not a web app or web service developer. I can take it forward pointed in the right direction - which would really help. Or not, if this can't be done, which almost seems the general concensus. But that at least would be an answer.

I still need an answer. Perhaps it's not an answer I can get on Stack Overflow, but it is an answer to a real question. A great question. I'll get it somewhere. But closing this Question was misguided.

Comment: I don't know why you tagged this as a bug, but please take a step back. Rather than assume you have asked what you call a "perfect question", perhaps inquire about what might be the motivation leading to closure. Perhaps there is a reason (which you might be able to address) which is not all that misguided after all. Keep in mind that closure is also not necessarily a permanent state. So it might help to take a somewhat more constructive stance.

Comment: Your question was wrong for Stack Overflow and so it was closed. Your rant about the closure doesn't make your question any less wrong for Stack Overflow. Your question was closed by five users, each vastly more experienced in contributing to Stack Overflow than you. What is more likely, that all five users have misinterpreted the site's policies and they are wrong, or that you are wrong? Instead of posting this rant, you should take a step back and *learn from your mistake*, rather than taking this ridiculous combative stance.

Comment: And should you wonder where all the downvotes are coming from, keep in mind that downvotes on Meta are [often used to express disagreement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). Most of them might simply indicate that they think your question was rightfully closed.

Comment: _"Ideally, someone would answer with what would have to be done, and I would be on my way."_ You'd mark the question as answered somewhere in there I hope"

Answer (score 15):

Yes, Stack Overflow encourages "little" questions in that questions should be specific, focused, and answerable without writing a book and/or a multi-page tutorial, and giving a lecture. Your question, in its current form, is not a good fit for SO because it lacks that specificity - `How do I do (insert huge, non-trivial task here)` is usually an indicator for a question that is too broad.

Still, you would have been likely to get some responses if your question hadn't been *ambiguous* as well: it seems really unclear what exactly you mean by making your app available to the Internet (I can think of two  options - providing your desktop app as-is through a terminal server setup, or building a web-app for the browser, usually based on HTML and JavaScript). These two are *entirely* different concepts that require a completely different answer. You made no effort to clear up that ambiguity, and your question was closed as a consequence.

If you want better feedback, try being more specific about what exactly it is what you want.